# Submitting two forms at once in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm working on a `ListView` which includes two forms, a search form and a filter form. Both of the forms ultimately change the view's `queryset` through its `get_queryset` method. I would like to make it such that when you search for something, the filters are persisted, and vice versa.

It is more-or-less working, but there is still one bug: whenever I search for something, a 'CLEAR FILTERS' button appears which should not be there:

[image]

In the template, the search form is included like so:

```
{% block search_form %}
  {% with action='dashboard:families' placeholder='Search Families' %}
    {% include '_search.html' %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

where `_search.html` is

```
{% load get %}

<form action="{% url action %}" method="get" class="left search col s6 hide-on-small-and-down" novalidate>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input id="search" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
        autocomplete="off" type="search" name="q"
        value="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}"
        data-query="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}">
    <label for="search" class="active"><i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i></label>
    <i data-behavior="search-clear"
        class="material-icons search-icon"
        {% if not search_form.q.value %}style="display: none;"{% endif %}>close</i>
  </div>
  {% if filter_form %}
    {% for field in filter_form %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ field.name }}" value="{{ request.GET|get:field.name }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

and the custom filter `get` simply implements the `dict.get` method:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def get(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

In short, the search form includes a hidden `filter_form` which gets submitted with the search query.

The part of the template which contains the filter form reads as follows:

```
          <form action={% url 'dashboard:families' %} method="GET" data-behavior="filters">
            <input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q.strip }}"/>

            <div class="input-field col s2">
              {{ filter_form.guide }}
              <label class="active">Guide</label>
              {% if filter_form.is_guide_filled %}
                <a href="" class="clear"><i class="material-icons tiny">clear</i></a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s2">
              {{ filter_form.status }}
              <label class="active">Status</label>
              {% if filter_form.is_status_filled %}
                <a href="" class="clear"><i class="material-icons">clear</i></a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s2">
              {{ filter_form.package }}
              <label class="active">Company / Package</label>
              {% if filter_form.is_package_filled %}
                <a href="" class="clear"><i class="material-icons tiny">clear</i></a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s2">
              {{ filter_form.next_outreach }}
              <label>Outreach</label>
              {% if filter_form.is_next_outreach_filled %}
                <a href="" class="clear"><i class="material-icons tiny">clear</i></a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s2">
              {{ filter_form.country }}
              <label class="active">Country</label>
              {% if filter_form.is_country_filled %}
                <a href="" class="clear"><i class="material-icons tiny">clear</i></a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s1">
              {{ filter_form.vip }}
              <label>VIP</label>
              {% if filter_form.is_vip_filled %}
                <a href="" class="clear"><i class="material-icons tiny">clear</i></a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s1">
              {{ filter_form.app }}
              <label>App</label>
              {% if filter_form.is_app_filled %}
                <a href="" class="clear"><i class="material-icons tiny">clear</i></a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>

            <a href="{% url 'dashboard:families' %}?q={{ request.GET.q.strip }}"
                data-behavior="clear-filters"
                class="btn-flat" {% if not filter_form.is_filled %}style="display: none;"{% endif %}>
              <i class="material-icons">close</i>Clear Filters
            </a>
          </form>
```

Note that the filter form also contains a hidden field named `q` with the search query. Since this is a `CharField`, it makes sense to set the `value` as `request.GET.q.strip`.

The problem is that if I drop into the debugger in the `FamilyFilterForm`, I see that that the form's data is a 'stringified' version of what I'd expect it to be:

```
ipdb> self.data
<QueryDict: {'q': ['Christine'], 'status': ['None'], 'next_outreach': [''], 'country': ['None'], 'vip': [''], 'app': [''], 'guide': ['6'], 'package': ['None']}>
```

Note how a `None` value has been converted into the string `'None'`. This causes the `is_filled` property of the filter form to 'think' that a value has been filled out, whereas actually there hasn't.

Instead, I would like to have the form's data be equivalent to

```
ipdb> from django.http import QueryDict
ipdb> query_dict = QueryDict('q=Christine&guide=6')
ipdb> query_dict.dict()
{'q': 'Christine', 'guide': '6'}
```

and in particular, if no filters are applied, it should be just an empty `QueryDict()` or `{}`.

How can I avoid the `request.GET` values from getting 'stringified' when passed as a `value` in a template in this fashion?

Comment: If you don’t want the `clear filters` to display at all delete your code at the bottom of the form. If it is supposed to display sometimes, your `if` statement looks wrong

Answer (score 0):

I managed to include the hidden `filter_form` correctly (with multiple choice fields correctly represented) by using the field's [`as_hidden`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5e06fa1469180909c51c07151692412269e51ea3/django/forms/forms.py#L582) property. So the `_search.html` template becomes

```
<form action="{% url action %}" method="get" class="left search col s6 hide-on-small-and-down" novalidate>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input id="search" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
        autocomplete="off" type="search" name="q"
        value="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}"
        data-query="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}">
    <label for="search" class="active"><i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i></label>
    <i data-behavior="search-clear"
        class="material-icons search-icon"
        {% if not search_form.q.value %}style="display: none;"{% endif %}>close</i>
  </div>
  {% for field in filter_form %}
    {{ field.as_hidden }}
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Similarly, the filter form contains

```
{{ search_form.q.as_hidden }}
```

to persist search queries.